# Raspberry pi 4, ina219 Bi-Directional DC Current Power Supply Sensor

Tags: python, sensors, i2c, raspberry-pi4

Good evening, I'm relatively new to raspberry pi 4 but I'm facing a problem. I am trying to use 4 ina219 sensors. But I need to givethem a different address (i2c) so that the raspberry pi can recognize them and get the data. I did all the necessary steps with pins A0 and A1. I also enabled i2c from the raspberry interface but the raspberry doesn't recognize them and can't run the code. If anyone has tried this before and could help me I would greatly appreciate it.....

Comment: Maybe better asked on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Have you checked the SCL and SDA signals with oscilloscope? Usually I²C needs to have pull up resistors to be adjusted depending on the physical line properties,